# The best way to create an html email newsletter

Tags: html, css

How do you compose an html newsletter that renders correctly in MS Outlook? My html looks bad, but good as a web page. I have the html written, and it looks good in chrome and IE, but within outlook, the styling is botched. I have used all inline CSS, as directed by other websites. Do you need special software, or are there any good training resources to help? In short, what is the best way to send out an html email newsletter? Here is a small snippet of my code, enough to give you the idea:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head> 
   <charset="utf-8">
   <title>GPA Newsletter</title>    
 </head>
```

```
 <div style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; background: gray; padding: 10px">               

    <div style="padding-bottom: 80px; background: linear-gradient(gray, white);"> 
        <h1 style="margin-top: 0;">Here is your September 2017 GPA Maintenance Newsletter</h1>          
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5xskeoF.jpg" alt="The newsletter logo" style="margin-top: 30px;   border-radius: 30px; border: 5px solid black; max-width: 100%; display: block; margin: auto;    width: 50%; argin-bottom: 40px;">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/uhdSAow.jpg" alt="The comcast logo" style="max-width: 100%;        display: inline; float: left; margin-left: 12%; margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <h2 style="text-align: right; padding-right: 15%; margin-bottom: 0;">September 2017</h2>            
    </div> 

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right to use all inline styles.  That's a good start.

Also, in my experience, the best way to create HTML newsletters is to just used **fixed pixel dimensions**.  **640pixels** wide is the guaranteed lowest common denominator (so it will work in ANY email client on any machine).  The more common width size I've seen lately is **720px**.  But I don't think percentages (% ) work at all.  Email clients just aren't as sophisticated in rendering HTML as browsers are.

Code School has a great little class that teaches how to build HTML emails. https://www.codeschool.com/courses/unmasking-html-emails

Answer (score 0):

When I make newsletters, I try to use only most supported methods, or at least methods that I remember and believe will work in almost all clients.
Then there are tools for testing the newsletter for example we use litmus.
Don't use divs (use tables), many clients are not rendering them properly. Background does not have enough support as well, ... (background-color is better).
You have to specify font family in many places, .... and this is just part of your code that is wrong.
There is no easy answer for this, just need some experience what works and what not, or try to use some framework or template.
https://foundation.zurb.com/emails/email-templates.html
This link might help you as well:
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Thank you both very much, this gives me some great leads to go on!